# Why are some lanes in my rhythm game not spawning notes from a midi file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a rhythm game for a university project. The game reads a midi file containing the charts of the level and assigns all the notes of a certain type to the different lanes. Every lane then calculates the spawn Y position of every note given the speed of the notes and spawns the notes accordingly. This seems to work but only 2 of the 6 lanes of the game (the second one and the fifth one).

Every lane has an array of timeStamps (being those the time of occurrence of each note). This array gets information from the SongManager that reads the midi file. Each lane has also an array of spawnPositionsY (the Y positions at which every note spawns). Every timestamp is paired with a Y position in order to spawn a note and have it on the controller of the lane at the exact timestamp. At runtime, I noticed that only the second and fifth lane populate the SpawnPositionY array, while the other lanes leave the array empty.

this is the code from the NewLane script:

```
public class NewLane : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Melanchall.DryWetMidi.MusicTheory.NoteName noteRestriction; //it limits the lane to a single note
    public KeyCode input; //key to press

    public GameObject notePrefab; //note associated with the lane
    public GameObject laneButton; //coloured button (controller) associated with the lane

    public float positionX; //X position of the lane

    public List<double> timeStamps = new List<double>(); //list of the time of occurrence of the different notes
    public List<float> notesPositionsY = new List<float>(); //list of all the Y position at which notes spawn 

    Vector3 spawnPoint;

    void Start()
    {
        SetPositionsY(); //populates spawnPositionsY
        Instantiate(laneButton); //instantiates the laneButton
        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(positionX, 0, 0); //creates the placement of the lane
        transform.position = newPos; //places the lane
        int i = 0;

        foreach (double timestamp in timeStamps) 
        {
            spawnPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x, notesPositionsY[i], -1); //creates the spawn position of the note
            Instantiate(notePrefab, spawnPoint, transform.rotation); //instantiates the note at that position
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void SetTimeStamps(Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Interaction.Note[] array) //reads the entire list of notes and saves the ones of this particular lane
    {
        foreach (var note in array)
        {
            if (note.NoteName == noteRestriction) 
            {
                var metricTimeSpan = TimeConverter.ConvertTo<MetricTimeSpan>(note.Time, NewSongManager.midiFile.GetTempoMap()); //...converts in metric time unit
                timeStamps.Add((double)metricTimeSpan.Minutes * 60f + metricTimeSpan.Seconds + (double)metricTimeSpan.Milliseconds / 1000f); //saves the timestamp 
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetPositionsY() 
    {
        foreach (double timestamp in timeStamps) 
        {
            notesPositionsY.Add(((float)timestamp * NewSongManager.Instance.noteSpeed) + NewSongManager.Instance.noteSpeed * NewSongManager.Instance.songDelayInSeconds); //(time of occurrence * speed) + offset
        }
    }
}
```

this is the NewSongManager script, if needed

```
public class NewSongManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static NewSongManager Instance; //instantiates the songmanager
    public AudioSource audioSource; 
    public NewLane[] lanes; //all the lanes

    public float noteSpeed = 0;

    public string midiLocation; //midi file path
    public static MidiFile midiFile; //midi file

    public int songDelayInSeconds = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        Instance = this; 
        ReadFromFile();
    }

    public void ReadFromFile()  //reads the midi file
    {
        midiFile = MidiFile.Read(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + midiLocation); 
        GetDataFromMidi();
    }

    public void GetDataFromMidi() //takes the data from the file
    {
        var notes = midiFile.GetNotes();
        var array = new Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Interaction.Note[notes.Count];
        notes.CopyTo(array, 0);

        foreach (var lane in lanes) lane.SetTimeStamps(array);

        Invoke(nameof(StartSong), songDelayInSeconds);
    }

    public static double GetAudioSourceTime()
    {
        return (double)Instance.audioSource.timeSamples / Instance.audioSource.clip.frequency;
    }

    public void StartSong()
    {
        audioSource.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error could be the timestamps or the midi file.  You need to isolate the issue better and give more info for us to help.

Comment: I looked at the timestamps array of every lane at runtime ad I can guarantee that they receive the correct informations, but only the two lanes described before actually generate the Y positions in the spawnPositionsY array

Comment: Can you post all the timestamps and speeds?

Comment: no, I can't, at the moment the speed is a fixed value of 10 for every note spawaned, and every lane has something like 120/150 timestamps each. the first 10 timestamps of the first 2 lanes are as follows. LANE 1 (2, 6, 8, 10, 17.328, 19.16, 20.992, 22.824, 26.259, 26.488, 28.32) LANE 2(2.5, 6.5, 8.5, 17.671, 18.932, 20.763, 21. 335, 22.595, 24.427, 24.656, 24.999). The first lane doesn't work as intended, the second one does.

Comment: I'm not sure why code works at all.  You have an array of zero rows for public NewLane[] lanes.  So the foreach will never do anything : foreach (var lane in lanes) lane.SetTimeStamps(array);

Comment: oh, that works because I give that array a value of 6 in the inspector, and then I pass it each individual lane complete with the according notePrefab and LaneButton. this way each lane is different from the other.

Comment: You cannot assign data to an object that has no memory.  You are creating what is known as Vapor Ware. You are lucky that app doesn't crash.